# Why does hibernate show the commit log before the inserts and updates?

Tags: java, hibernate

Hibernate logs show this:

```
[debug] o.h.e.t.i.TransactionImpl - begin
do stuff...
[debug] o.h.e.t.i.TransactionImpl - committing
do more stuff... inserts, updates etc...
[debug] o.h.e.j.i.JdbcCoordinatorImpl - HHH000420: Closing un-released batch
```

When it's "supposed" to do this

```
[debug] o.h.e.t.i.TransactionImpl - begin
do stuff...
do more stuff... inserts, updates etc...
[debug] o.h.e.t.i.TransactionImpl - committing
```

I wrapped the entire thing in a transaction, so I don't imagine it's a problem with my code. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate have 3 states: Transient , Persistent and Detached. I think it will show `commit` when change from transient state to persistent state. However, it is not means the transaction really commited. Just means object has been controlled by Hibernate and ready to commit to database some time(depends on Hibernate internal mechanism).  Please correct me if I am wrong.